Multicolumn seach vector with postgresql
In a postsgresql v13 database, I want to add a search vector on a table, and i want to put several columns (not all the same type) in that vector.
I have some 7 text columns, 1 json column and 1 jsonb column :/
In my jsonB column, I can have a json like {email: 'david@labyrinth.com, phone: '010203040506', firstname: 'David', lastname:'Goliath'}
In a ideal scenario, i would not like to have the json keys in the vector.
I also wish I could search on '@labyrinth.com' and get a result
For now I manage to do the following, but json key are indexed and partials emails are not searcheable.
ALTER TABLE company ADD COLUMN search_vector tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
to_tsvector('french', name || ' ' || comment || ' ' || address || ' ' || postalCode || ' ' || cga || ' ' || manager || ' ' || franchise || ' ' || coalesce(cast(advantages as text), '') || ' ' || coalesce(cast(contacts as text), ''))')
) STORED;

Is there a way to do so ?

What are all those backwhacks doing?  (Other than causing syntax errors)

Thanks for the alert, I removed them to be more readable. (they were here because the string as also in single quote)

That sounds like a task for trigrams rather than FTS. You can combine these.

Not a solution for you current problem, but potentially much more powerful: pgvector. See https://youtu.be/FDBnyJu_Ndg?si=IbMZLaXwIckC0jKy

Thanks for this resource, I didn't know about pgvector, I'll have a look.

full-text search doesn't work well for partial matching.  You would probably want a trigram index for that.  I don't think you told us which of the named columns corresponded to the jsonb column.
create index on t using gin ((jsonb_col->>'email') gin_trgm_ops)

select * from t where jsonb_col->>'email' like '%@labyrinth.com';

You could create a multi-column gin index combining columns handled with different operators, but I don't think there is any point. Just make different indexes.
